# Ask user to run makefile from root mode

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

I have a makefile and configure shell in my project. I wrote code to ask user to run configure shell in root mode using the following code.

```
[ "$(whoami)" != "root" ] && exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
```

But when I run '`make install`'
I need to ask user to run from root mode.
So I just copied the code from the configure shell and copied it in another shell script file called '`runasroot.sh`'. Then I run this shell script from the `make install`.

```
install:
    @echo About to install XXX Project
    ./runasroot.sh
    find . -name "*.cgi" -exec cp {}  $(SCRIPTDEST)/ \;
```

When I run the above code, I got the below error.

```
About to install XXX Project
./runasroot.sh \;
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

runasroot.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$(whoami)" != "root" ] && exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
```

Comment: Remind me not to use your code.  Don't do anything about forcing `root` in the makefile.  Document in the README or INSTALL file that the user shoujld run `make install` as `root`.  It is improbable that you need `root` privileges for the compilation.  It is best if you don't even demand `root` for the install — allow the user to install it as themselves if they have permission to write in the relevant directories.

Comment: Does `runasroot.sh` contain only the code you show above?  This does not look like it's reproducible.  See the instructions for creating a [mcve].

Comment: Do you expect everybody to run with no root password, or just happily type the password whenever prompted?

Comment: Basically, you only know how to check for root with a bash shell.  Don't do that, check for root within the make file. It avoids the make file calling a shell script just to check this one thing.  @Pipo shows you how to check from the make file below.

Answer (score 7):

```
target:
       @if ! [ "$(shell id -u)" = 0 ];then
             @echo "You are not root, run this target as root please"
             exit 1
       fi
```

Answer (score 6):

### Explanations

You can use `ifneq` to check that the user is not root and echo a message for instance, not performing the actual action is the user was indeed a `root` user. Since the id of the `root` user is usually `0` on a UNIX-like operating system, we can check that the user ID is `0` (or not) in a conditional.

### Proposal solution

```
install:
ifneq ($(shell id -u), 0)
    @echo "You must be root to perform this action."
else
    @echo "TODO: The action when the user is root here..."
endif
```

### Output

```
$ make install
You must be root to perform this action.
$ sudo make install
TODO: The action when the user is root here...
```

### External resources

[Conditional Parts of Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)

[The shell Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)

[Recipe Echoing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html)

[Man for the id function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html)

[What is a root user](https://www.ssh.com/iam/user/root/)

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistakes done here.

The first problem is what you're trying to do. It is very bad form to require root as part of the build process. For the build part, try to not require root for compiling anything. If you need to create special files as part of the packaging, use `fakeroot` or `fakeroot-ng` to get the same effect without any actual privilege escalation.

For install, just let the user run your entire make file as root, if she so chooses. Many operations that *usually* require root sometimes don't. For example, `make install` does not require root if the install is to a `DESTDIR` where the user has privileges.

If you are dead set on doing this anyway, however, your flow is completely wrong. While `runasroot.sh` does exactly what you want it to do, it only does so for itself. When you look at your make receipt:

```
install:
    @echo About to install XXX Project
    ./runasroot.sh # <<-- this line runs as root
    find . -name "*.cgi" -exec cp {}  $(SCRIPTDEST)/ \;
```

The `runasroot.sh` line runs as root, but the `find` line is a different process, and is completely unaffected.

That would be true for regular shell script, but it's doubly true for a make receipt. In a shell script, each command gets its own process. In a make receipt, each command gets its own ***shell***. Your `runasroot.sh` does not, and cannot, affect the privileges under which the find runs.

So, what you are trying to do is both impossible and unwanted. Just try to install and fail if you don't have enough permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Automatically call `make` again with `sudo` and all parameters preserved if user is not root:

```
install:
ifneq ($(shell id -u), 0)
    sudo make $@
else
    echo Your commands here...
endif
```